# How to define a line in 2D by two parameters for all cases?

Tags: linear-algebra

One can define any line by two points (x1,y1,x2,y2) using four parameters, or by a point and angle (x1,y1, alpha) using three parameters. Coefficients (a,b) can define ALMOST any line using y=a*x+b, but cannot define vertical lines.

I realize that two numbers (0.a1a2a3a4.. and 0.b1b2b3b4..) can be encoded in one (as 0.a1b1a2b2a3b3a4b4..), hence, one number of this type is enough to encode any line. But is there a cleaner way to encode any line with two parameters?

---

Hough transform answers my question. Please make it an answer.

Comment: Angle and distance from origin.

Comment: @Rahul How does that encode a ***line*** (unless you specifically mean one passing through the origin)?

Comment: @Bye_World: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Theory

Comment: Interesting.$\ \ \ \ $